# Traffic Flow using proximity

Tags: jquery, curl, here-api

I would like to preface this question by stating that I have little to no experience in coding.  I am a civil engineer trying to use the HERE Web Developer (https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-proximity).  I am trying to measure the average daily traffic flow of an intersection, (Union St. and S. 7th street located in Hudson, NY), by using their "Flow Using Proximity" tool.  I used their interactive map to get the location I need. The outputs I receive are 2 small lines of code either in the form of a cURL command or a Jquery snippet, as well as a response which is a much longer code.  I'm not sure what to do with this information.  I've tried messing around in my command prompt (windows), and googling the solution but have had no success.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
{

  "RWS": [

    {

      "RW": [

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9962,

                    "DE": "RT-23B/Green St/Fairview Ave",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 2.9171

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 28.1,

                      "SU": 28.1,

                      "FF": 36.35,

                      "JF": 1.8149,

                      "CN": 0.79

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9961,

                    "DE": "RT-23B/RT-9G/Columbia St",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 0.47965

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 21.9,

                      "SU": 21.9,

                      "FF": 25.91,

                      "JF": 1.23922,

                      "CN": 0.73

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9960,

                    "DE": "RT-23/CR-31/Blue Hill Rd/Claverack Rd",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 2.93703

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 34.22,

                      "SU": 34.22,

                      "FF": 39.77,

                      "JF": 1.1159,

                      "CN": 0.75

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "c2b4c351-2648-4904-b1c0-b49f99ba379d",

          "LI": "120-00065",

          "DE": "US-9",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        },

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9961,

                    "DE": "RT-23B/RT-9G/Columbia St",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 2.93241

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 37.33,

                      "SU": 37.33,

                      "FF": 39.15,

                      "JF": 0.37199,

                      "CN": 0.75

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9962,

                    "DE": "RT-23B/Green St/Fairview Ave",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 0.46704

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "SSS": {

                        "SS": [

                          {

                            "LE": 0.20144,

                            "SP": 19.4,

                            "SU": 19.4,

                            "FF": 23.77,

                            "JF": 1.46996

                          },

                          {

                            "LE": 0.26559,

                            "SP": 14.7,

                            "SU": 14.7,

                            "FF": 29.83,

                            "JF": 4.18221

                          }

                        ]

                      },

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 14.55,

                      "SU": 14.55,

                      "FF": 26.84,

                      "JF": 3.10863,

                      "CN": 0.82

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 11256,

                    "DE": "CR-20/Atlantic Ave/W Atlantic Ave",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 2.89161

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "SSS": {

                        "SS": [

                          {

                            "LE": 0.5138,

                            "SP": 32.17,

                            "SU": 32.17,

                            "FF": 31.49,

                            "JF": 0

                          },

                          {

                            "LE": 0.2258,

                            "SP": 13.25,

                            "SU": 13.25,

                            "FF": 30.82,

                            "JF": 5.74754

                          },

                          {

                            "LE": 1.58967,

                            "SP": 31.8,

                            "SU": 31.8,

                            "FF": 36.64,

                            "JF": 1.05773

                          },

                          {

                            "LE": 0.29861,

                            "SP": 17.02,

                            "SU": 17.02,

                            "FF": 39.77,

                            "JF": 5.79891

                          },

                          {

                            "LE": 0.26371,

                            "SP": 24.68,

                            "SU": 24.68,

                            "FF": 36.88,

                            "JF": 2.64618

                          }

                        ]

                      },

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 24.13,

                      "SU": 24.13,

                      "FF": 35.42,

                      "JF": 2.12783,

                      "CN": 0.88

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "186f971c-5bfd-4a03-a9e0-fbb73f51ccbd",

          "LI": "120+00065",

          "DE": "US-9",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        },

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9807,

                    "DE": "US-9/Fairview Ave",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 0.0232

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 15.53,

                      "SU": 15.53,

                      "FF": 24.23,

                      "JF": 2.25641,

                      "CN": 0.7

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9806,

                    "DE": "RT-23/RT-9H",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 2.73383

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 34.9,

                      "SU": 34.9,

                      "FF": 38.59,

                      "JF": 0.76487,

                      "CN": 0.83

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "de36a279-d245-4ee9-a865-1b467f74699a",

          "LI": "120-00407",

          "DE": "RT-23B",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        },

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9807,

                    "DE": "US-9/Fairview Ave",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 2.73344

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 35.87,

                      "SU": 35.87,

                      "FF": 37.41,

                      "JF": 0.32929,

                      "CN": 0.79

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "a9131de6-c5ee-4ab8-8a93-70d1f5f3ba83",

          "LI": "120+00407",

          "DE": "RT-23B",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        },

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 8173,

                    "DE": "RT-23B/Green St",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 1.53152

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 32.75,

                      "SU": 32.75,

                      "FF": 36.29,

                      "JF": 0.77946,

                      "CN": 0.77

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "6f2db066-7bea-4574-935d-5ca0c407c138",

          "LI": "120-00437",

          "DE": "RT-66",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        },

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 8173,

                    "DE": "RT-23B/Green St",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 0.00989

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 19.32,

                      "SU": 19.32,

                      "FF": 24.85,

                      "JF": 1.18287,

                      "CN": 0.88

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 12097,

                    "DE": "CR-18/Fish and Game Rd",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 1.52163

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 32.92,

                      "SU": 32.92,

                      "FF": 36.72,

                      "JF": 0.82953,

                      "CN": 0.89

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "ac8fa105-bf4a-48df-a1a3-c21529db2cbe",

          "LI": "120+00437",

          "DE": "RT-66",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        },

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 30611,

                    "DE": "Allen St",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 2.6211

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 45.22,

                      "SU": 45.22,

                      "FF": 44.93,

                      "JF": 0,

                      "CN": 0.79

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9549,

                    "DE": "US-9/Park Pl",

                    "QD": "-",

                    "LE": 0.77347

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 13.29,

                      "SU": 13.29,

                      "FF": 20.13,

                      "JF": 1.97996,

                      "CN": 0.77

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "4f9ef3d6-2953-4ff2-9397-54871eb7235a",

          "LI": "120+00624",

          "DE": "RT-9G",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        },

        {

          "FIS": [

            {

              "FI": [

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9549,

                    "DE": "US-9/Park Pl",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 0.02276

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 27.88,

                      "SU": 27.88,

                      "FF": 29.83,

                      "JF": 0.52159,

                      "CN": 0.71

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 30611,

                    "DE": "Allen St",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 0.7507

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 9.97,

                      "SU": 9.97,

                      "FF": 18.89,

                      "JF": 2.98633,

                      "CN": 0.73

                    }

                  ]

                },

                {

                  "TMC": {

                    "PC": 9548,

                    "DE": "RT-23/Claverack Rd",

                    "QD": "+",

                    "LE": 2.69519

                  },

                  "SHP": [],

                  "CF": [

                    {

                      "TY": "TR",

                      "SP": 42.98,

                      "SU": 42.98,

                      "FF": 45.17,

                      "JF": 0.38933,

                      "CN": 0.75

                    }

                  ]

                }

              ]

            }

          ],

          "mid": "7f54b74b-2aff-45f0-b9d8-431f1dcc1c6f",

          "LI": "120-00624",

          "DE": "RT-9G",

          "PBT": "2020-02-24T21:35:00Z"

        }

      ],

      "TY": "TMC",

      "MAP_VERSION": "202001",

      "EBU_COUNTRY_CODE": "1",

      "EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE": "A0",

      "TABLE_ID": "20",

      "UNITS": "imperial"

    }

  ],

  "MAP_VERSION": "",

  "CREATED_TIMESTAMP": "2020-02-24T21:35:00.000+0000",

  "VERSION": "3.1",

  "UNITS": "imperial"

}
```

Comment: What would you do with the data? If all you need is the flow data, the response _is_ your data. The cURL and jQuery snippets are recipes for re-doing the query.

Comment: I have included the response the website produces.  Frankly, I am unsure of how to read this.  I do not see anything that resembles the data I am looking for.  Specifically I am looking for the number of cars going through this intersection per day.  I expect the number to be in the mid-to-high hundreds.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find much documentation about that return format either. You may just want to consider contacting Here - https://developer.here.com/contact-us

Comment: Can you share the code you tried? 
https://developer.here.com/tutorials/switch-to-here-js-geocode/